# Highlighting data according to whether the same value turns up in another file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, conditional-formatting, excel-indirect

In Excel I want to highlight certain names in my table `TAB1`. My table looks like this (but is a lot longer):

```
Name    Surname
Luke    Skywalker
Han     Solo
Leia    Organa
...
(up to 50 names)
```

I also have another table `TAB2` (saved in another Excel file) with SOME of the names. What I want is:

Whenever a name turns up in `TAB2`, its occurrence in `TAB1` should be highlighted (color, or font size or such).

I read a (German) [tutorial](http://www.tippscout.de/excel-vergleichen-mit-anderer-tabelle_tipp_5891.html), but this gives me a mistake. My code is the following:

```
="VERGLEICH(A2;Teilnahmeliste ausgefüllt!B2:B51;0)"
```

(I'm working with the German version of Excel; VERGLEICH means compare in English; "Teilnahmeliste ausgefüllt" is the name of the second file, a.k.a. `TAB2`.)

I think my mistake is that I have not included the name of the spreadsheet (`TAB2` has three spreadsheets; the one I need is called "Komplett").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, here it is no use pointing to a workbook containing several sheets without mention of which sheet.
2. The real name of your "TAB2" workbook has a space in it, so in formulae references need to be enclosed - single inverted commas are usual.
3. The full name of the workbook is very likely to include an extension (I assume `.xlsx`) and if so this needs to be part of the formula.
4. Given the need for both workbook name and sheet name the syntax requires the use of brackets, so: `'[Teilnahmeliste ausgefüllt.xlsx]Komplett'!` to refer to a specific sheet in specific book.
5. You say "My code is the following: `="VERGLEICH(A2;Teilnahmeliste ausgefüllt!B2:B51;0)"`" but that is not code - the double inverted commas mean it is merely a string of text.
6. As shown you do not have a specific 'key' - for example a means to differentiate between `Luke` (Skywalker) and say `Luke` (Evangelista) as well as Luke `Skywalker` and Nat `Skywalker`. A conventional solution to this is to create unique keys such as with:

> =A1&"|"&B1

in C1 and copied down to suit (assuming `Name` is in A1 in both sheets). Often only keying the lookup array is required, as the corresponding key in the search formula may be created within the search formula "on the fly" however I recommend the above formula in *both* sheets.

7. VERGLEICH means compare in English but the Excel function name in English is [MATCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php).
8. The next issue is that Excel's Conditional Formatting will not normally 'span' workbooks:

> You may not use references to other workbooks for Conditional Formatting criteria.

However, use of [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) can be a workaround.

9. Using INDIRECT does however introduce another issue - both workbooks must be open for the function to work effectively.
10. So, with English function names and delimiter I think you should select ColumnC (in either sheet - depending upon which comparison you want) then
11. HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

> =MATCH(C1,INDIRECT("'[Teilnahmeliste ausgefüllt.xlsx]Komplett'!$C:$C"),0)>0

<kbd>Format...</kbd> with formatting of your choice, OK, OK.

12. Where the German language and locale version for the formula may be:

> =VERGLEICH(C1;INDIREKT("'[Teilnahmeliste ausgefüllt.xlsx]Komplett'!$C:$C");0)>0

Comment: Well, basically the code itself **is** the answer. For such short statements, I find it ok to give no comment. However, longer code parts should have always a comment. It gives me some faith that the poster knows what (s)he does. But when I see some long code in an answer without any comment or explanation, then my motiviation in reading the post goes dramatically down. Some voice in my head says *"Will you invest time in reading something which might be total crap?"*

Comment: this is a very useful answer indeed, because it explained multiple of my beginner's mistakes. It will prevent you guys from having to answer all those questions separately ;-) thanks a lot indeed!

Comment: @pnuts: I needed the solution for work, so if I had just had the formula, I would have copy-pasted; not much more. This awesome answer actually made me and the whole office spend time on what we did wrong before. I'm pretty sure we would not have done that with just the formula! So once more: It was really helpful! thanks!